# Error creating bean with name 'blJaxrsObjectMapperProvider' and 'blJaxrsObjectMapperProvider'

Tags: jboss7.x, broadleaf-commerce

I build a project on JBoss 7.0 and 7.1, but I receive the following error when I try. I'm waiting for your help.

JDK 1.7

Thanks

11:47:16,733 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) [ WARN] 11:47:16 MergeXmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blJaxrsObjectMapperProvider': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'blWrapperOverrideTypeModifier' is defined
11:47:17,604 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) [ERROR] 11:47:17 ContextLoader - Context initialization failed

11:47:17,605 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blJaxrsObjectMapperProvider': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'blWrapperOverrideTypeModifier' is defined

11:47:17,605 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
11:47:17,605 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
11:47:17,605 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
11:47:17,605 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
11:47:17,605 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
11:47:17,606 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
11:47:17,606 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
11:47:17,606 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
11:47:17,606 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
11:47:17,606 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
11:47:17,606 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
11:47:17,607 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
11:47:17,607 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
11:47:17,607 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
11:47:17,607 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoader.java:146)
11:47:17,607 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368)
11:47:17,607 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821)
11:47:17,607 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70)
11:47:17,608 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
11:47:17,608 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
11:47:17,608 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
11:47:17,608 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
11:47:17,608 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
11:47:17,608 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'blWrapperOverrideTypeModifier' is defined
11:47:17,609 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
11:47:17,609 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168)
11:47:17,609 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281)
11:47:17,609 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
11:47:17,609 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:461)
11:47:17,609 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
11:47:17,610 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
11:47:17,610 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
11:47:17,610 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
11:47:17,610 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
11:47:17,610 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-10)   ... 22 more
11:47:17,610 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/admin]] (MSC service thread 1-10) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blJaxrsObjectMapperProvider': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'blWrapperOverrideTypeModifier' is defined
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308) [spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) [spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434) [spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoader.java:146) [broadleaf-common-5.0.1-GA.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'blWrapperOverrideTypeModifier' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:461) [spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435) [spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559) [spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) [spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:]
    ... 22 more

Answer (score 1):

If you have `javax.ws.rs.core` on your classpath then it is required to define the bean

```
<bean id="blWrapperOverrideTypeModifier" class="org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.api.WrapperOverrideTypeModifier">
```

in you're applicationContext.